# Add Multiple row of data in databse at once

Tags: php, html, textbox

i have few field of data such as product , amount and barcode.The system just show 1 row of data insert form that contain the 3 field.when i completed insert the first row, then second row of textbox will auto generate, i can do it by microsoft access, can i do so for php ?

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
    </form>


<?php 
    if(isset($_POST[$i])){
    $i++;
?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
    </form>
<?php }?>
```

it work for the first and second textbox, but how can i continue to create more textbox accordingly?

Comment: I can barely understand what you mean. Can you edit your question and make it more clear?

Comment: You can use `echo` for your html tags.

Comment: Why you don't use 3 text boxes for product, amount & barcode instead of single text box ?

Comment: i assume the single text box is the 3 text boxes, another row means another product.
for example, first row i insert ( bread,3,12341241 ) for product,amount and barcode respectively. then i need it to auto generate another new row of textbox for me to insert another product.

Comment: Are you using the `$i` to insert product data? If not, why don't using a static textbox name instead of a running number? Such as `<input type='text' name='product' />`

Comment: i assume the $i is an array ( product[$i] ) . sorry if my coding is not complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

say your file name is **1.php** and you will submit the form to **1a.php**

### 1.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            a=0;

            function generate()
            {
                if(document.getElementById(a).value!="")
                {
                    var new_input=document.getElementById(a).cloneNode(true);
                    //document.getElementById(a).type="hidden";//uncomment this statement to hide the previous input box.
                    new_input.id=++a;
                    new_input.title='product_no:'+(a+1);
                    new_input.value="";
                    document.getElementById('input_section').appendChild(new_input);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Give some value first.");
                    document.getElementById(a).focus();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="1a.php">
            <span id="input_section">
                <input type="text" onFocus="this.name='prod[]'; this.id=a; this.title='product_no:'+(a+1);"/>
            </span>
            <input type="button" value="Insert&Generate" onClick="try{generate()} catch(e){alert(e)}">
            <input type="submit" value="INSERT ALL">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### 1a.php

```
<html>
    <?php
        if(count($_POST)==0)
        {
    ?>
            <script>
                alert('No record to insert.')
                location.href="1.php";
            </script>
    <?php   
        }
        $con=mysqli_connect(...);// connect to database
        foreach($_POST['prod'] as $prod_info)
        {
            $prod_info_arr=explode(",",$prod_info);
            $sql="insert into tab1(product, amount, barcode) values('".$prod_info_arr[0]."', ".$prod_info_arr[1].", '".$prod_info_arr[2]."')";
            mysqli_query($sql);
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

## This is what you wanted. Check it.

edit: just added comment on the statement `document.getElementById(a).type="hidden";` to make the filled textbox not disappear.

Comment: -1 for using deprecated PHP method. mysql_* method are deprecated since PHP 5.5 –

Comment: that means every time i insert the data, it will process on the server site?
how about if I want to get all the data and save it at once in DB?

Comment: If you want that you need javascript. it is possible even without AJAX.

Comment: do you have any reference?

Comment: Wait for the update. I'm going to include it in my answer using JavaScript.

Comment: What shoud i input for the textbox ?

Comment: as you specified in your comment `bread,3,12341241`. input this in this format itself. the attributes will be separated before the insert operation by the `explode()` function in my code.

Comment: Dont forget to give particulars in `mysqli_connect()` and give proper table name in the sql before executing.

Comment: it works,but still have some minor error. how if i want to display them 1 by 1 before save? is that possible ?

Comment: after key in the first textbox, the data will remain there.
and another textbox will appear below of the first textbox.
the data will keep and generate without pressing any button.

Comment: 1 more question, if I want to seperate them to 3 textbox, what should i do ? Sorry for troubling.

Comment: Yes that is definitely possible. Going to add it soon.

Comment: For separate input fields Check my edit history. I did it before but as per your specification I removed it. Sorry this is a redundant job. I'm updating the code to make all the data appear on screen all together that you want. Check the update.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have dynamic input fields, so that second and third input boxes are displayed only when the first input box is filled, use an AJAX code.

Comment: is that exactly what u want?

Comment: Ill show an example code, but under what condition should the second input box should be displayed? When what input is entered to the first input box?

Comment: ya..when 1st textbox is filled then 2nd textbox will appear. when 2nd textbox is fill, 3rd textbox will appear.. this is what i mean. sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score -1):

This must be what you want. Since you have not mentioned clearly under what condition the second input field should be displayed, i assumed if 'try' is inserted in the first input field, second input field is shown.

```
 <?php 
 echo "<script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=='')
      {
      document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML='';
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','get.php?q='+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form  method='post' action=''>
   First input<input type='text' name='name'  onclick='showUser(this.value)' /></br>
   <div id='txtHint'></div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>"; 
    ?>
```

And in get.php file the following code;

```
  <?php
  $q = $_GET['q'];
  if($q == 'try'){
  echo "Second input<input type='text' />";
  }
  ?>
```

Hope this will help. And change the get.php code according to the condition you want the second input field to be shown. 
This code works. After entering try in the first input field again click inside the text field. And then second input field will be shown.

Comment: after i key in the first textbox, no respond given. What should I do to make it works?

Comment: Rather than adding a new answer modify your existing answer. This may fetch you some fresh votes.

Comment: I edited my new code. My previous code and this code both works. You have to again click inside the input field to see the result. As i edited the code, enter 'try' and again click inside the input field. Then you will get the second input field.

Comment: @user2892997 did u try this?

Comment: i just try.not working also. when i key in the first textbox , no respond given. what should i type as an input ?

Comment: It is working. According to my above code, enter 'try' (without quotation marks) and again click inside the input field. Then you will see the result. First code should be in a separate file and second code should be in 'get.php' file.

Comment: its work. thanks !!! but how to continue doing so ? what I mean is when i do the same thing for 2nd textbox, 3rd textbox will appear